# python regex for multiple words not matching

Tags: python, regex

So I have a regex like this -

```
[\w\s.<>/]* is [boom|box|cat]+[\w\s<>/]+[fun|lame][\w\s<>./]*
```

but this matches

```
<something>things/something> is brah <HELLO>loc</HELLO> suburb.
```

why?

Answer (score 3):

`[...]` is a character class, it will match any individual character between the brackets, i.e. your `[boom|box|cat]` is identical to `[abcotx|]`. You want `(boom|box|cat)` and `(fun|lame)`.

Comment: but doesn't that mean I capture those words? I don't want to capture them

Comment: Yes, they happen to capture things. You don't have to use the backreference if you don't want to.

Comment: IF you're very concerned about the capturing (for whatever reason) you can use a non-capturing group and do `(?: ... )` instead of `( ... )`